# How can I tell Which targets are executed (not skipped) when running bazel build with aspects

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

As part of our efforts to create a bazel-maven transition interop tool (that creates maven sized jars from more granular sized bazel jars),
we have written an `aspect` that runs on `bazel build` of the entire bazel repo and writes `txt` files `outputs`.

1. We want to write these aspect `outputs` **only** for non-cashed targets.
2. Even better will be to have a list at the end of the run that contains all the targets that were run (not skipped due to them being cached)

Are 1. and 2. possible?

Answer (score 0):

> We want to write these aspect outputs only for non-cashed targets.

I am not 100% sure what you mean here. It is undetectable if the target was cached or not. However, `output` files will be cached. If you run the same build with the same aspect, only the files that are not up-to-date will be updated.

> ... to have a list at the end of the run that contains all the targets that were run

We have a flag `--experimental_show_artifacts` that prints you all the artifacts that were built.